# How to extract phone number from Call.Details in CallScreeningService?

Tags: android

I'm making a call blocker for Android api 29. In order to do this, I have a class that extends CallScreeningService as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService.html). My app can detect incoming and outgoing calls, but I don't know how to extract the phone number from Call.Details:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class CallScreenService extends CallScreeningService {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
        CallResponse.Builder response = new CallResponse.Builder();
        Log.i("CallScreeningService", callDetails.toString());
    }
}
```

The log outputs "tel:**********" which I suspect means I don't have sufficient permissions to read the phone number. In Main I'm requesting permissions for all of the following:

```
   android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
   android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
   android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
   android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,
   android.Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS,
   Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

Additionally here is my Manifest for my CallScreening class:

```
    <service android:name=".phoneHandlers.CallScreenService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

How can I read the phone number in Call.Details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the current phone number already connected to the call you need to use [Call.Details#getHandle()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/telecomm/java/android/telecom/Call.java#724).

So inside your `onScreenCall` :

```
@Override
public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
   Log.i("Phone number", callDetails.getHandle().toString());
}
```

Comment: if your number contains a country code, you need to decode it with UTF-8

Comment: That's the number of the other person's phone. What about the number of the current user (to determine which SIM card is used for it) ?

Comment: Can we get name from CallDetails?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getSchemeSpecificPart. This will only return phone number and no need to handle string further as compared to `callDetails.getHandle().toString());`

```
@Override
public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
    String number = details.getHandle().getSchemeSpecificPart();
    Log.i("Phone number", number);
}
```